# Timeout in paramiko (python)

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, scp, paramiko

I'm looking for a way to set a timeout for this:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The connection timeout can be set with the `timeout` parameter (that indicated the number of **seconds** for the time out as described [here](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect)) of the `connect` function.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password, timeout=10)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
sftp.close()
```

Comment: @kukosk It would help if you mentioned the unit in which timeout is to be given, I guess its seconds.

Comment: What's the default timeout, I don't think I found it mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) either, although they do mention `timeout (float) – an optional timeout (in seconds) for the TCP connect`

Comment: Here's some more background, if timeout is not specified the client falls into blocking mode: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts

Comment: Lots of default timeout definitions pop up at https://github.com/jbouse-debian/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/transport.py, all given in seconds

Comment: Note that `timeout` parameter sets TCP timeout. There are also `banner_timeout` and `auth_timeout` which you may want to adjust as well.

Comment: @jxramos are you sure about blocking behavior? When I tested an unreachable address with no timeout argument, the connect timed out after 75 seconds.