# Timeout for sftp.get in Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I found this to be useful [Setting timelimit for sftp.get() of Paramiko module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222684/setting-timelimit-for-sftp-get-of-paramiko-module) but the callback function here also takes into account time for connection establishment. I need to restrict only the SFTP `get` file transfer time. I tried to modify the callback function as below but it doesn't work. Here's my code.

```
class TimeLimitExceeded(Exception):
    pass

def _timer(start_time, timelimit=5):
    elapsed_time = time.time()-start_time
    if elapsed_time > timelimit:
        raise TimeLimitExceeded

if __name__=="__main__":

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    try:
        start_time=time.time()
        sftp.get(remote_path, local_path, _timer(start_time))
    except TimeLimitExceeded:
        print ("The operation took too much time to complete")
    finally:
        sftp.close()
        ssh.close()
```

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl , I've recently started working in python. In the above code the callback function also takes into account connection establishment time. I need to restrict only the file transfer time. I tried to modify the callback function but it doesn't work if I use the start time to be the time just before the sftp get call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path, _timer(start_time))
```

You are not passing `_timer` as callback here, you are calling `_timer` function and passing its return value (it has none).

This is correct (as the original code does):

```
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path, _timer)
```