# How to make a separate thread for a function - Python?

Tags: python, sftp

On this part of python script below, I want to use a sftp.put() in a separate thread/processus and kill it after a while, all in the same script. I don’t know how to write this using Thread or multiprocessing.

Is someone may show me a simple way to do it please?

**Ubuntu 18.04,
paramiko 2.6.0**

```
[...]
raspi = paramiko.SSHClient()
raspi.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
raspi.connect(ip , username= "", password= "" , timeout=10)
sftp = raspi.open_sftp()        

[...]   

sftp.put(source, destination , callback=None, confirm=True)  

raspi.close()

[...]
```

**Update 1**

Ok, so this code is working, but if I use all the arguments of the sftp.put(), he doesn't work and return a syntax error:

```
 [...]
    raspi = paramiko.SSHClient()
    raspi.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    raspi.connect(ip , username= "", password= "" , timeout=10)
    sftp = raspi.open_sftp()        

    [...]   

    th = threading.Thread(target=sftp.put, args=(source, destination))
    th.start()
    th.join()

    raspi.close()

    [...]
```

Don't work with (invalid syntax):

```
th = threading.Thread(target=sftp.put, args=(source, destination, callback=None, confirm=True))
```

Comment: Please try solving this using either threads or multiprocessing and then show what you tried and how it doesn't work

Comment: ok thanks, in update 1 this seems to work but not when I use all the arguments.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? Where does source and destination come from? I cannot see it in your code anywhere. Also what sftp-library are you using? I cannot see any imports in your example code. Also callback and confirm should be in kwargs and not args

Comment: It seems that you have resolved this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58844902/850848#58890159 - So if you know the answer, please post it here.